# Magento 2 - Find LESS version

Tags: magento2, less

How can I figure out the version of LESS used by Magento 2?

I need it for a bug report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find less.min.js here:
vendor/magento/magento2-base/lib/web/less/less.min.js

In the first few lines you can see the version:
"Less - Leaner CSS v2.3.1"

For me (Magento 2.3.2) it's v2.3.1